# AWS API Gateway with Lambda and KeepAlive (persistent connections)

Tags: keepalive, amazon-lambda, amazon-api-gateway

I'm a bit confused about Keep-Alive with AWS API Gateway.
Is this something I need to configure? or maybe be careful with this setting?
Because I will use API Gateway to execute Lambda functions, and because Lambda price depends on the execution time I'm not sure if this will impact somehow on it.
I couldn't find any reference to this so maybe the question does not make sense because API Gateway timeout is always 30 seconds?
Is API Gateway supporting persistent connections?

Answer (score 1):

lambda receives events and is charged by time the code runs. Keep-Alive as described here https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/customize-integration-timeouts-in-amazon-api-gateway/ just specifies how long the API Gateway waits for the lambda result. So if your lambda runs 300ms, this is what you will pay for. If it runs 50 seconds the API Gateway will always timeout.